# Word for a non-subscript symbol

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word in English that refers to the symbol that has another symbol associated with it as a subscript, superscript, leftscript or rightscript? For example (lacking Latex here), if I have the Einstein's equation *E=mc<sup>2</sup>*, then `c` has a superscript the number `2` in a subexpression *c<sup>2</sup>*, but how would I refer to `c` itsself in a subexpression *c<sup>2</sup>*?

Some words that come to my mind are middlescript, mainscript, main symbol, ground symbol, base symbol, etc. but all of these are just my inventions I have never heard elsewhere.

Comment: [Baseline symbol?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript) (Which is to say, the symbol at the baseline.)

Comment: What’s hard about *E* = *mc²*? :)

Comment: superscriptand?

Comment: I agree with @TusharRaj - in typography, one would normally say that the c in that equation is **on the baseline**. Likewise, in math, the number operated on by the exponent is the **base**. Using a term involving "base" or "baseline" should be clear in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typography, normal characters are said to *sit* on the [baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29), the provided Wikipedia link says (in part)

> the **baseline** is the line upon which most letters "sit" and below which descenders extend.

[image: A diagram showing terms to do with letter height and positioning on the baseline]